# How to set straight alignment for my android recycler view list?

Tags: android

I got problems on the recycler view alignment. Each time I'm creating a recycler view list, the alignment for horizontal or vertical is not really straight.

Based on the red line I've marked, showing the inconsistency of my CardView @ Layout view alignment.

My expected outcome is that recycler view list is in a straight line, either vertical or horizontal.

My current display output:

[image: sample of my recycler view list]

My current codes for the recycler view list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
                custom:donut_progress="30"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chapterNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chapter 1"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chapterTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Standard Form"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    adapterListChapters = new AdapterChapterList(chaptersList);

    recyclerViewChapters = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewChapterView);
    recyclerViewChapters.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewChapters.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewChapters.addItemDecoration(new SpacingItemDecoration(2, Tools.dpToPx(this, 8), true));
    recyclerViewChapters.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewChapters.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewChapters.setAdapter(adapterListChapters);


    adapterListChapters.setOnClickListener(new AdapterChapterList.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, ChapterList obj, int pos) {
            final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parent_view_chapter, "Item " + obj.chapterTitle + " clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
```

AdapterChapterList.java

```
package xxx.xxxx.components.adapter;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress;
import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.model.ChapterList;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterChapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ChapterList> chapterLists = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnClickListener onClickListener = null;

    public AdapterChapterList(List<ChapterList> chapterLists) {
        this.chapterLists = chapterLists;
    }

    public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public View lyt_parent_chapter_list;
        public TextView chapterNumber,chapterTitle;
        public DonutProgress learningProgress;
        public OriginalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chapterNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chapterNumber);
            chapterTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chapterTitle);
            lyt_parent_chapter_list = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent_chapter_list);
            learningProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);
            learningProgress.setTextSize(40);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_chapter_list,parent,false);

        vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder)
        {
            OriginalViewHolder view = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;
            final ChapterList c = chapterLists.get(position);
            view.chapterNumber.setText(c.chapterNumber);
            view.chapterTitle.setText(c.chapterTitle);
            view.learningProgress.setDonut_progress(String.valueOf(c.learningProgress));

            view.lyt_parent_chapter_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(onClickListener == null) return;
                    onClickListener.onItemClick(v,c,position);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chapterLists.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, ChapterList obj, int pos);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please also share the code in your java class related to the recyclerview.

Comment: @Nero I've shared my MainActivty and AdapterChapterList files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Recycler view listItem

1.Using layout_weight requires layout_width to be 0dp t function properly

Here Is Updated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
                custom:donut_progress="30"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chapterNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chapter 1"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chapterTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Standard Form"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In case If Above Layout Doesn't Solve Your Problem Try **Removing** this line of code

```
    recyclerViewChapters.addItemDecoration(new SpacingItemDecoration(2, Tools.dpToPx(this, 8), true));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback..I want to try first.

Comment: Please Revert Back With The Results :-)

Comment: The result still the same... ;(

Comment: That is Weird!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163095/discussion-between-abu-hassan-and-shrey-gupta).

Comment: Gotcha! You were right...I remove that line..then it's ok.. ;)